# Verify proof of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^{-1/2}}<2\sqrt{n}$ for every $n\ge1$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

The following is exercise 2.6.20 (c) from Tom Apostol's *Calculus Volume 1*, I'd like someone to verify my proof. I'm also interested in simpler alternative proofs.

> Determine if the following is true and if so prove it:
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^{-1/2}}<2\sqrt{n} \qquad \text{for every} \qquad n\ge1 $$

$$ 2\sqrt{n} = \int_0^nt^{-1/2}dt=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-1}^kt^{-1/2}dt>\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-1}^k{k^{-1/2}}dt=\sum_{k=1}^n{k^{-1/2}} $$

Comment: Induction on $n$?

Comment: Your proof is good, and is probably the simplest.

Comment: Nice. And  can  get a lower bound  in a similar way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof through the integral test is fine. Induction is a viable alternative: let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Since $S_1<2$, it is enough to check that $S_{n+1}-S_n < 2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)$, but the last inequality is equivalent to:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}} $$
that is trivial since $x\to\sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$.